# particle effects?

Tags: android, particles

I want to achieve particle effect when an object is found. I have relative Layout on which I have many ImageViews are Placed now when user click on the ImageViews I want some particle effect to happen ( I do not want sprite animation ). How will I achieve it ? any good reference or help ?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem as you, and following the recommendations, I implemented it, and also open sourced it as a library.

https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

It is quite easy to use and also very lightweight.

You probably had this sorted out since the question is quite old, but I hope it will be useful  to other people with the same problem.

Comment: it's great. 
I want to learn to create it myself can you guide me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check this question which has some good link to Patricle Effects tutorial

[How to create fireworks particle graphics effect on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408204/how-to-create-fireworks-particle-graphics-effect-on-android)