# Animation of fireworks on the screen of the app

Tags: android, android-animation

In animation I am trying to implement the fireworks animation on the screen a.k.a the Tango Android app. How do I implement this on the screen?

1. Do I have to start a transparent activity with running a short clip of fireworks with a transparent background?
2. Something else?

I am adding some images from the Tango app where the fireworks animate on the screen.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rblgZ.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7pYk.png)

Comment: I don't know anything about this. But, i seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5408204/940096) one may be his helps you

Comment: Do you draw it on top of your activity and views or on top of another app?

Comment: I am not sure where to draw, what do you suggest?